# Fixing render blocking CSS on WP

Tags: css, wordpress

Hello I am trying to fix render blocking CSS recommendation from Google Page speed.

```
<style>here goes critical path</style>
<link rel="preload" as="style" media="all" href="wp-content/cache/autoptimize/css/autoptimize_fb3761d5ff1bb5dcb1bc273f35788f8e.css" onload="this.rel='stylesheet'" />
<noscript id="aonoscrcss">
<link type="text/css" media="all" href="wp-content/cache/autoptimize/css/autoptimize_fb3761d5ff1bb5dcb1bc273f35788f8e.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</noscript>
```

I use Autoptimize for this purpose, so I inserted critical path and checked defer CSS. However Google doesn't count this as a fixed recommendation.
From this code part, is there any issues that causing it, or it something else? Any hints on how to troubleshoot this issue?

And also Google shows 2 blocking css files with the same name and url.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to be honest, I've been dealing with these kind of stuff for ages. The only thing I manage to do is to add "inline" css to all pages... Yes, it's a pain in the *ss. but after all... google is ok with it..

the solution would be to get ALL css rules for EACH page and add it as an inline-css in your html (minimized of course.)

not sure if that's the best way to go, however, that's what solved the issue for me..

cheers

Answer (score 0):

With Autoptimize, you can enable the **Inline all CSS?** option, the problem will gone.

Answer (score 0):

Your "critical css" is likely considered insufficient by GPSI @Eng80lvl, you'll have to look into that (regenerating it elsewhere or tweaking it yourself).

"inline all" fixes the "render blocking"-warning, but will (except is you have very little CSS) see GPSI complaining about "prioritize visible content" (as the amount of inlined CSS will cause your actual content to be available later, even if part of the same response).